# How to mange big amount users at server side?

Tags: java

I built a social android application in which users can see other users around them by gps location. at the beginning thing went well as i had low number of users, But now that I have increasing number of users (about 1500 +100 every day) I revealed a major problem in my design.

In my Google App Engine servlet I have static HashMap that holding all the users profiles objects, currenty 1500 and this number will increase as more users register.

**Why I'm doing it**

Every user that requesting for the users around him compares his gps with other users and check if they are in his 10km radius, this happens every 5 min on average.
That is why I can't get the users from db every time because GAE read/write operation quota will tare me apart.

**The problem with this desgin is**

As the number of users increased the Hashmap turns to null every 4-6 hours, I thing that this time is getting shorten but I'm not sure.
I'm fixing this by reloading the users from the db every time I detect that it became null, But this causes DOS to my users for 30 sec, So I'm looking for better solution.
I'm guessing that it happens because the size of the hashmap, Am I right?

I would like to know how to manage **ALL** users profiles with max aviablity.

Thanks.

Comment: "*As the number of users increased the Hashmap turns to null every 4-6 hours*" - can you clarify this part? What does this `null` mean? Who clears the `HashMap`?

Answer (score 1):

I would not store this data in the HashMap as it does not really scale if you run on multiple instances and furthermore you use a lot of memory.

Why do you not use some different storages like MongoDB which is also available 'in the cloud'? (e.g. www.mongohq.com).

If you would like to scale you need to separate the data from the processors. E.g. have x servers running your servlet (or let Google AppEngine scale this on themselves) and have the data at a different place (e.g. in a MongoDB or PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your whole design. Storing all users in one huge `HashMap` won't scale (sooner or later you'll have to cluster your application). Also the complexity of your algorithm is quite high - you need to traverse the whole map for each user.

A much more scalable solution would be to use a [spatial database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database). All major relation databases and some NoSQL products offer geospatial indexing. Basically the database query engine is optimized for queries like: *give me all the records with near this given point*.

If your application is really successful, even an in-memory map will be slower than enterprise-grade geospatial index.